# Could it be something to do with X?

Tags: sentence-construction

When we wanted to use the phrase "it has something to do with x" in affirmative-question form and in possibility sense, is it correct to say:

> Could it be something to do with X?

and

> Could it have something to do with X?

Comment: The first phrasing could suggest that X helps explain or cause "it", whereas the second only stafes that "it" is associated with X.    correlation vs. causation.  My neck stings; could it be something to do with that bee I heard buzzing around me?

Answer (score 1):

[This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+something+to+do+with%2C+have+something+to+do+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) makes it pretty clear which is used more often.

However, I'm not sure that "is something to with X" is actually ungrammatical. For instance, the [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/be-have-something-to-do-with-sth) states that the verb can be either.

So I'd say that "it could be something to do with X" is probably grammatical, but so uncommon that it will sound a bit odd.

The situation is complicated by the existence of a great number of equivalent statements which use forms of "to be": "It is similar to X", "It is connected to X", "It is associated with X", "It is an aspect of X", and probably more.